# How to stop initial validation in Angular, on form fields that are reused in tab like components?

Tags: angular, validation, input

As the question is ambigious let me explain:

There are serious of input fields in a component. These are shared, just like tabs, many times as user switch through accounts.

Since the fields are always there and not on a modal, if I enter values for one account and have validation as I type and may be success as I finish, next time when I chose another account, the validation stays there even though may be there is no value, nothing is touched yet.

Fields have their logic; I am using MD bootstrap directive alongside with valid, invalid classes tied to .touched, .dirty hooks when error occurs.

The problem is when I switch to another form and the values might be different but validation still happens. See the attached images:

[image]

[image]

I think I need something like viewInit, or may be destroy the form and create again each time. Or just reset validation until any touch or focus or value added.

Comment: Have you tried form.reset()

Comment: I am thinking that all I need, may be, to delete the invalid and valid classes each time possibly inside a DoCheck or AfterContentChange hooks in input directive which ever is the right thing to do. The MdbInputDirective does not have anything like that, I actually changed it a bit to make my own directive.

Comment: @SlobodanGajić I haven't tried form.reset() no. I am not using angular form builder by the way if it is related.